# Maximum Likelihood and De Finetti's Theorem

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

I have a question about whether it is possible to use De Finetti's representation theorem for maximum likelihood estimation.

De Finnetti's theorem states that for any exchangable infinite sequence of random variables $(X_1,\ldots,X_n,\ldots)$, we can represent the probability distribution $f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ as a mixture
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \int \prod_{i=1}^n g(x_i \mid H) \, dP(H).$$

where the variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are conditionally independent given $H$ and  $P(H)$ is a probability distribution over $H$.

I would like to theoretically show that $P(H)$ can be estimated if we observe a matrix $(x_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n$ where each row $(x_{i1},\ldots,x_{in})$ is drawn independently from the distribution $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

The idea would be to do a two step estimation:

- For each $i,$ estimate $H_i =_\text{def} \operatorname{argmax}_H \prod_{i=1}^n g(x_i \mid H)$
- Once we observe $H_1,H_2,H_3,\ldots$ use these to estimate $P^* = \operatorname{argmax}_P \prod_{i=1}^n \Pr(H_i \mid P).$

It seems that for this idea to work, each $H_i$ would have to live in a compact set (otherwise, maximum likelihood estimation in the first step does not necessarily work). But since $H$ is drawn from $P(H)$ and $P$ does not necessarily have a compact support, this won't work.

Is there a way to parametrize $P$ to ensure it has compact support?

Comment: Supposing $P$ is the normal distribution with expectation $H$ and variance $1,$ then you can find the MLE for $H$ based on $n$ observations despite the fact that the support is the whole real line, which is not compact. It is true that compactness is sufficient to imply there is a unique argmax, but it is not necessary.